# how to upload file from local file system directly without using file input?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

If we know the local absolute path of the file can we upload the file automatically without file input  .Are there any plugins to do that ? browsers dont allow generally but is there any workaround to this ?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the HTML5 `FileSystem` API - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem

Please check compatibility thoroughly as this is still an ***experimental technology***.
A few examples can be found [here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/using-the-html5/9781449311384/ch04.html).

Comment: lets say I have my file in the downloads folder and I know the absolute path , will I still be able to load it from there  without using file input . ?